# Colored sections and subsections with amsart (since amsart doesn't work with sectsty)

Tags: color, amsart, sectsty

I am writing a set of notes for which so far, I had been using the `article` class, but have recently decided to switch to `amsart`. I had a bunch of declarations (using the `sectsty` package) to make sections, subsections, etc. colored.

Pretty much everything else works in my LaTeX document when I compile with `article` replaced by `amsart` *except* for the `sectsty`-based commands, and I get an error message which reads

> /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sectsty/sectsty.sty:296: Package sectsty Error: The sectsty package doesn't work with
>   (sectsty)                                     this document class.

Since my sole purpose is to have different section and subsection colors, I am looking to replace the following set of commands

```
\chapterfont{\color{RubineRed}} % sets colour of chapters (works only with sectsty)
\sectionfont{\color{RubineRed}} % sets colour of sections (works only with sectsty)
\subsectionfont{\color{blue}} % sets colour of subsections (works only with sectsty)
```

with something that achieves the same effect. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As pointed out by cfr, `article` doesn't have chapters, so the `\chapterfont` command above is redundant.

Comment: Neither `article` nor `amsart` supports chapters.

Comment: @cfr, okay you can ignore the chapters command. It never gave me an error (with sectsty and article) because I never used a chapter in the first place. The question pertains to **color** in sections and subsections, when amsart is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\section` and `\subsection` commands:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\color{RubineRed}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\color{blue}}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]